# IdentityServer4 unauthorized despite providing valid token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I'm trying to protect an api with IdentityServer4.

IdentityServer Startup Configuration:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
        .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
        .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.GetApiScopes());
}
```

Config:

```
public class Config
{
    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource>
        {
            new ApiResource("myAPI", "Test API")
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },
                AllowedScopes = { "myAPI" }
            }
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> GetApiScopes()
    {
        return new List<ApiScope>
        {
            new ApiScope("myAPI", "Test API")
        };
    }
}
```

When I call my IdentityServer with a Post Request to `http://localhost:5000/connect/token` I receive a valid token, so that should work.

[image]

API Startup Configuration:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options => {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.Audience = "myAPI";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            });

        services.AddAuthorization();

        services.AddDbContext<ApiContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("ApiDb"));
        services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
    }
```

The API Controller has the `[Authorize]` attribute.

I'm trying to call the controller with a token that I got from the IdentityServer.
Unfortunately, I get a 401 unauthorized despite providing the token as a bearer token.

Is something in my configuration wrong or why do I still get a 401?

Thanks in advance

-- EDIT: full Startup.cs of the API

```
public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
                    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options => {
                // base-address of your identityserver
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";

                // if you are using API resources, you can specify the name here
                options.Audience = "myAPI";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            });

        services.AddAuthorization();

        services.AddDbContext<ApiContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("ApiDb"));
        services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you get a 401, do you see a corresponding error on identity server ?

Comment: no I don't see an error in the identityserver console window :(

Comment: can you show your full startup.cs on the web api

Comment: yes of course, I've added it to my post at the bottom

Comment: in your configure method, add `app.UseAuthorization()` underneath `app.UseAuthentication`